# Access params in Pentaho from scripted data source?

Tags: scripting, groovy, reporting, parameter-passing, pentaho

I am currently developing a parameterized report using Pentaho.

Pentaho defines parameters that can be given at the time of generation or inserted by some external source via a Pentaho API.

Now comes the question. I have a scripted data source in groovy and would like to parameterize it a bit. How can I/what's the best way to *access* the parameters (defined in pentaho) in a scripted data source?

If you use an SQL data source you can directly say ${ParamName} and it replaces the string; however if you use a scripted source this doesn't seem to work.

Any and all comments are more than welcome!

P.S. Sorry for this seemingly trivial question, but we all know how badly documented pentaho is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do either of these pages help?

http://www.sherito.org/2011/11/pentaho-reportings-metadata-datasources.html

http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-96689.html

Comment: Thanks, that did it! 

Just to actually answer the question, you can do: `dataRow.get("ParameterName");`

Note: The dataRow object contains other useful meta info as well (access via getters/setters). Thus, it can be used when developing complex scripts.